# Linear independence - Generalized eigenvector chains

Tags: linear-algebra

For matrix $A$ and its eigenvalue $\lambda$ with very high multiplicity, can we prove that:

If

$f_j \in (ker((A-\lambda I)^i)-ker((A-\lambda I)^{i-1}))\hspace{0.5cm}  for \hspace{0.5cm} j = 1, ...,n, \hspace{0.5cm}$ and
$ \hspace{0.5cm}f_j$'s are linearly independent

Then

$v_j = (A-\lambda I)f_j, \hspace{0.5cm} for \hspace{0.5cm} j = 1, ...,n \hspace{0.5cm}$ are also linearly independent.

If not, could you give a counterexample?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $i$ the same for every $f_j$?  That is, is every $f_j$ taken from $\ker(A - \lambda I)^i \setminus \ker(A - \lambda I)^{i-1}$ for some exponent $i$?

Comment: Yes, i is fixed in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question (as I understand it) is no.  We could consider any Jordan block, but for illustrative purposes I'll stick to the Jordan block of size $3$ associated with $\lambda = 0$.  That is,
$$
A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0}.
$$
Take $i = 3$.  We have $\ker(A - 0I)^{i-1} = \operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2\}$.  For our $f_j$, it suffices to take linearly independent vectors outside of this span.  For instance, let's take
$$
f_1 = (1,1,1), \quad f_2 = (0,1,-1), \quad f_3 = (0,1,1).
$$
Here $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are linearly independent, but $Af_1,Af_2,Af_3$ fail to be linearly independent (since all three vectors have a third coordinate of $0$).

Comment: $dim(ker((A-0I)^3) - ker((A-0I)^2) =1$, how do you get three linearly independent vectors?

Comment: I don't see how your observation regarding dimensions is relevant. As was the requirement, $f_j$ are linearly independent and satisfy $(A - 0I)^3f_j = 0$ and $(A - 0I)^2 f_j \neq 0$.  You should check this yourself if you don't believe it.

Comment: I assume that you meant to write 
$$
\dim(\ker((A-0I)^3)) - \dim(\ker((A-0I)^2)) =1
$$

Comment: Sorry, I am little bit confused. When I wrote $(A−0I)^2f_j≠0 $, I meant not in the null space of $(A-0I)^2$, but I think it is not the same.

Comment: I have edited the question. If it does matter, sorry for that, if not I need to think.

Comment: @Pasha Those are indeed the same

Comment: @Pasha Note that the set-difference $ker((A-\lambda I)^i)-ker((A-\lambda I)^{i-1}$ will **not** be a vector space

Comment: Ok, can't we still proceed?

Comment: @Pasha proceed with what exactly?  I still have no idea what you're trying to accomplish by proving this apparently false statement.

Comment: @Pasha the question you have constructed makes sense if that is what you are asking.  Really, I was pointing out that your statement $dim(ker((A-0I)^3) - ker((A-0I)^2) =1$ makes no sense because the object whose dimension you are trying to find is not a vector space.

Comment: I understand it now. But can't we have n linearly independent vectors in the difference set, and then check the independence of the corresponding v vectors? Is it apparently wrong just because the difference set is not a vector space?

Comment: What do you mean by "the corresponding $v$-vectors"? Do you mean the vectors $(A - 0 I)f_j$? If that's what you mean, then that's exactly what I did in the example in my answer, so I don't understand why you're asking that question.

Comment: I am asking, because in our Linear System Theory MSc. class, we learnt a certain method for finding vector chains for finding Jordan form and the corresponding transformation matrix. But if it fails, then I am confused how are we going to construct the chains. Just taking any linearly independent vector for any chain?

Comment: Based on your question and this conversation, it seems as though you have misunderstood the method.

Comment: The problem is, your $f_1, f_2 and f_3$ should also be linearly independent from the basis for $ker(A-0I)$ and $ker(A-0I)^2$. So it cannot be three vectors. Maybe I can't express it in right mathematical terms in my question.

Comment: Once you figure out exactly what it is that you want to ask, you should post that question.  I would suggest that you make a post describing the algorithm and then ask why it is that the particular step you're worried about should work.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. But I could not explain my problem.