# Linear Independence - Generalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

For matrix $A$ and its eigenvalue $\lambda$ with very high multiplicity, and fixed power $i$ can we prove that:

If

$$(A-\lambda I)^if_j=0,\hspace{0.5cm} (A-\lambda I)^{i-1}f_j \neq 0$$
for $j = 1, ...,n$, and $f_j$'s are linearly independent  and the matrix

$M = [f_1 ...f_n e_1 ... e_m]$, where $e_k$'s are the basis vectors for $ker((A-\lambda I)^{i-1})$

is of full column rank,

Then
$$v_j = (A-\lambda I)f_j$$
for $j = 1, ...,n$ are also linearly independent.

If not, could you give a counterexample?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My [counterexample for your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3477387/81360) is also a counterexample for this one.

Comment: As I said on your last question: what I recommend is that you outline the entire procedure by which you are meant to find generalized eigenvectors, then ask for an explanation of the specific step that is confusing

Comment: Because 
$$
\ker(A-\lambda I) \subseteq \ker(A - \lambda I)^{2} \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \ker(A - \lambda I)^{i-1},
$$
the statement "$f_j$'s are linearly independent of the basis vectors of the kernels $ker((A- \lambda I)^m)$, for $m= 1, ..., i-1$" is equivalent to saying that each $f_j$ lies outside the kernel of $\ker(A - \lambda I)^{i-1}$.

Comment: Do you accept that basis vectors of $ker(A-\lambda I)^{i-1}$ is not zero? Then how can you find three vectors in $R^3$ linearly independent from these vectors?

Comment: What do you mean by how?! I have given you an example where I do exactly this!

Comment: In $\Bbb R^3$, the $xy$-plane, which is defined as
$$
\{(x,y,z): z = 0\}
$$
is certainly a non-zero subspace. However, the vectors
$$
f_1 = (1,1,1), \quad f_2 = (0,1,-1), \quad f_3 = (0,1,1)
$$
are outside of this subspace and are linearly independent. In fact, if you were to randomly generate $3$ vectors in any reasonable way, there is a very good chance that you'll end up with a set of vectors with this exact property.

Comment: Ok. but these vectors are not linerly independent of the basis vectors of the xy plane.

Comment: Also in your previous example, f's were linearly independent, but not independent of the basis vectors of $ker(A-0I)^{i-1}$.

Comment: yes they are. A vector $f$ is "linearly independent of the basis vectors of the $xy$ plane" if and only if $f$ is not an element of the $xy$ plane.

Comment: f is not an element of xy plane, but xy plane is element of $span(f_1, f_2, f_3)$

Comment: All right, then you should be phrasing your question differently.  I think the condition you should be using is 
$$
\operatorname{span}\{f_j : j = 1, \dots , n\} \cap \ker(A - \lambda I)^{i-1} = \{0\}.
$$
This is not the idea conveyed by your statement "$f_j$'s are linearly independent of the basis vectors of the kernels $ker((A- \lambda I)^{i-1})$".

Comment: Ok. It is equivalent that matrix with columns of these vectors is full column rank, right?

Comment: Yes: it is equivalent to the statement that the matrix with columns $e_1,\dots,e_m$ and $f_1,\dots,f_n$ has full column-rank, where the $e_j$ form a basis for $\ker(A - \lambda I)^{i-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hold for any $i \geq 2$.

Suppose for contradiction that $f_1,\dots,f_n$ are linearly dependent.  That is, there exist coefficients $c_i$ such that
$$
0 = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i (A- \lambda I)f_i = (A - \lambda I)\sum_{i=1}^n c_i f_i.
$$
We may conclude that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n c_i f_i \in \ker(A - \lambda I) \subseteq \ker(A - \lambda I)^{i-1},
$$
which contradicts our premise.

Comment: We said that $ker((A-\lambda I)^i) -  ker((A-\lambda I)^{i-1})$ does not form a vector space. So, although $f_j$'s are not on the kernel of $(A-\lambda I)^{i-1}$, their linear combination can be, isn't it?

Comment: I agree with the second sentence.  However, I don't see the connection between the two sentences of your comment.

Comment: So is your answer still valid?

Comment: You shouldn't agree with my second sentence, because linear combination of $f_j$'s cannot be in $ker(A-\lambda I)^{i-1}$. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Pasha you're right, I must have read that incorrectly.